# Unity importing textures incorrectly

Tags: import, unity-game-engine

So I have this problem where when I import, (by dragging and dropping, or manually importing), the colours get mixed up. Like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYMVA.png
(Don't have enough rep for image post.)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks for reading this, and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the right side, in inspector you have your texture import settings and you have chosen `compressed` type.

If you are so pixel-perfect here, you should choose one of uncompressed setting, which suits your needs - could be RGBA 32bit or 16bit. Then, without a compression these colours should be as original.

Comment: This fixed my color issue, thanks. But I have a new problem now, there are now "marching ants" in the texture for no reason. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/yCU1m51.png)